# List multiple taxonomies from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress question,

I have custom post type

3 taxonomies

and multiple terms within each taxonomy

The below code will spit out a list of terms within "Custom_Taxonomy"

How can I make it spit out the list from "Custom_Taxonomy2" within the same custom post type ?

```
$terms = get_terms( 'Custom_Taxonomy' );

echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

I've been trying the following solutions , but none of them work , im not much of a php coder. (Please dont give me a downvote , im trying here :-) )

```
$terms = get_terms( 'Custom_Taxonomy' AND 'Custom_Taxonomy2' );
$terms = get_terms( 'Custom_Taxonomy' || 'Custom_Taxonomy2' );
$terms = get_terms( 'Custom_Taxonomy' && 'Custom_Taxonomy2' );
$terms = get_terms( 'Custom_Taxonomy', 'Custom_Taxonomy2' );
$terms = get_terms( 'Custom_Taxonomy' 'Custom_Taxonomy2' );
```

Comment: same code with the name of the taxonomy you want to fetch?

Comment: Hehe ,, I just figured that out , and im using that solution now.. But I was wondering if it was possible to use this code like $terms = get_terms( 'Custom_Taxonomy' AND 'Custom_Taxonomy2' ); ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch the results for multiple taxonomies you just pass a array into the name field

```
  $terms = get_terms( array( 'Custom_Taxonomy', 'Custom_Taxonomy2'), $args );
```

Comment: This works, it was right in front of me the whole time on wordpress developer page ,, i just didnt have the brain to put the array in play.. Thank you for the solution David !

Comment: One question , If there are two terms from different taxonomies ,,, with the same name ,,,,, does that have any downside ? or would it spit both names out ?

Comment: they are two different terms, so it will output both. You prob need to think about your architecture, should a term be in two taxonomies? Prob not!

Comment: Well ,, The post type is called Meetings ,, then I have 3 taxonomies called "City-1" "City-2" "City-3" and each city has their department terms ,, some of them have the same name as the other taxonomies have.... I think im doing the architecture correctly , please advice if not :-)

Comment: its up to yourself, I dont know your project but generally speaking you could have one tax for location and another for the department terms. That way there is no duplication and you can see the posts for department tags across all cities if needed by visiting the tag page